# Xamarin.ios add DatePickerView and PickerView in AlertController

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

It's possible put a DatePicker and PickerView in a Alert controller in xamarin.ios like this?
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai3rI.png)

I've try this:

```
UIDatePicker datePickerView = new UIDatePicker(new CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, 300));
        var calendar = new NSCalendar(NSCalendarType.Gregorian);
        var currentDate = NSDate.Now;
        var components = new NSDateComponents();

        components.Year = -60;

        NSDate minDate = calendar.DateByAddingComponents(components, NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None);

        datePickerView.MinimumDate = minDate;
        datePickerView.MaximumDate = NSDate.Now;
        datePickerView.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;


        UIAlertController actionSheetAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Data di nascita", "Seleziona un'opzione dalla lista", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);


        actionSheetAlert.View.AddSubview(datePickerView);

        actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Aggiungi", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => {

        }));

        actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, (action) => Console.WriteLine("Cancel button pressed.")));


        this.PresentViewController(actionSheetAlert, true, null);
```

This is the result:
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55tBM.jpg)

Can you provide a complete example? thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can create our own `UITextField` to achieve the effect from your screenshot, here is my custom textField for you referring to:

```
public class MyTextField : UITextField
{
    private UIDatePicker inputView;
    private UIView inputAccessoryView;
    public override UIView InputView
    {
        get
        {
            if (inputView == null)
            {
                UIDatePicker datePickerView = new UIDatePicker();
                var calendar = new NSCalendar(NSCalendarType.Gregorian);
                var currentDate = NSDate.Now;
                var components = new NSDateComponents();

                components.Year = -60;

                NSDate minDate = calendar.DateByAddingComponents(components, NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None);

                datePickerView.MinimumDate = minDate;
                datePickerView.MaximumDate = NSDate.Now;
                datePickerView.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;

                inputView = datePickerView;
            }
            return inputView;
        }
    }

    public override UIView InputAccessoryView
    {
        get
        {
            if (inputAccessoryView == null)
            {
                UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 44));
                UIBarButtonItem item = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, (sender, args) =>
                {
                    NSDateFormatter formatter = new NSDateFormatter();
                    formatter.DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
                    this.Text = formatter.ToString(inputView.Date);
                    this.ResignFirstResponder();
                });
                UIBarButtonItem flexibleItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, null);
                toolbar.SetItems((new UIBarButtonItem[] { flexibleItem, item }), false);

                inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
            }
            return inputAccessoryView;
        }
    }
}
```

Override the `InputView`(put your datePicker in it) and `InputAccessoryView`(a toolbar with "Done")

At last we can use it like:

```
MyTextField textField = new MyTextField();
textField.Placeholder = "Enter something";
textField.Frame = new CGRect(0, 100, 200, 200);
View.AddSubview(textField);
```

Comment: @StefanoToppi Glad it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) :

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

What you could use is a custom controller or view that you will build from scratch, that you would modally present and dismiss and have full control of.

I think the highest level of customization you could get on AlertController is what you can find here :

[Tutorial to add textfields / buttons on alert](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-alert-controller-in-ios-10-swift-3--cms-27589)

Comment: Thanks for replay, other question it’s possible insert in a popup?